# too many values to unpack on dictionary key value iteration

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value, valueerror

Getting an error **too many values to unpack**. Can anyone help me to solve it?

```
friendship = {'nino': ["tamari", "nika", "lela", "dato"],
              'dato': ["tamari", "nino"],
              'tamari': ["nino", "dato", "lela"],
              'nika': ["nino"],
              'lela': ["nino", "tamari"]
}
def f(**friendship):
    sia={}
    for i in friendship.values():
        m = min(i)
        for k,v in friendship.items():
            sia.update({k:(len(v))})
        low = min(sia.values())
        res = [x for x,y in sia if sia.items() if y == low]

    print(str(res) + " has " + str(low) + " friends")   ------ getting an error on this line.
print (f(**friendship))
```

Comment: print (f(friendship))

Comment: The error is actually on `res = [x for x,y in sia if sia.items() if y == low]`. And if you try @High-Octane 's suggestion, the error becomes `TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: What is the method's goal ? What result do you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the unpacking at `x,y in sia` to have key/value use `items()` and remove the useless `if`, like this

```
[x for x, y in sia.items() if y == low]
```

Also you *can* remove the `**` operator at both places because it's useless it you directly pass a dict, and it causes to flat the data, then pack it again in the method